# Z3 solver difference logic python api

Tags: logic, z3, smt, z3py

I've been trying to do something like this in python:

```
(set-option :smt.arith.solver 1)
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const y Int)
(assert (>= 10 x))
(assert (>= x (+ y 7)))
(maximize (+ x y))
(check-sat)
```

I've been able to do it for a solver (`solver.set('smt.arith.solver', 1)`), but cannot do it with the Optimize class. Is it possible to write something like the above in python?

Also, does the solver that has been set to difference logic throw an error if it gets a regular integer linear program?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of stating the logic is to provide the SMT-LIB name of the logic when you create the solver instance, using the SolverFor() factory (see https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/z3.html )

It is not necessary to set a logic to get Z3 working, so it might be worth getting to a working version of your problem without worrying about the logic.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there's something similar for optimization problems? I haven't found anything in the docs. I have a working version, but I have been getting poor performance, that's why I'm trying to see if switching to this logic helps (I actually only need difference logic to state my problem).